# Prove that the function $f(x) = (x_2-x_1^2)^2 +x_1^5$ has only one stationary point which is not extreme

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

> Prove that the function $$f(x) = (x_2-x_1^2)^2 +x_1^5$$ has only one
>   stationary point which is not a local minimizer or local maximizer

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 2(x_2-x_1^2)(-2x_1)+5x_1^4$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 2(x_2-x_1^2) = 0 \implies x_2 = x_1^2$$

substituting in $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 5x_1^4 = 0 \implies x_1 = 0 \implies x_2 = 0$$

So $(0,0)$ is the only stationary point. I'm not going to calculate the hessian because in these exercises it's always inconclusive. Let's analyze a neighborhood of $(0,0)$:

What if I try:

$$f(\sqrt{x_2},x_2) = \sqrt{x_2}^5$$

can I say that this changes sign since it's a odd degree polynomial with roots only on $0$? Therefore $(0,0)$ is not an extreme point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot say that, since $\sqrt{x_2}^5$ is always non-negative. But you can say that $f(x_1,{x_1}^2)={x_1}^5$, which can take any real value.